# Why my codes give timeout error on hackerrank problems, timeout on huge list inputs

Tags: python-3.4

I'm a beginner python coder(self learning online), i started to solve coding problems at hackerrank but i am having hard time figuring out why my code is giving timeout error.
I lack guidance, Please guide me what should i learn to understand implementing faster to run codes.

**example problem i coded** -

> We have words list in a magazine and a word list required to make
>   note. we have to check if magazine has all the words that we need to
>   make the note. print 'Yes' if all words available, print 'No' if not.

```
mag = 'ive got a lovely bunch of coconuts'.split()
note = 'ive got some coconuts'.split()
```

> i have defined two function -

below function gives timeout for big word list and i don't understand why.
this function simply check if each word required is in magazine and i pop out the word already used.

**function 1**

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    ans = 'Yes'    
    for i in note:        
        if i not in magazine:
            ans = 'No'
            break
        else:            
            magazine.pop(magazine.index(i))
    print(ans)
```

**Function 2 (running very fast and pass all test (i followed someone's code))**

this function make a dictionary, loop through each word in magazine and store word count in dictionary.
and again loop through words in dictionary, compare to words needed and then gives output and still this is faster then directly checking words in two list.

```
def checkMagazine2(magazine, note):
    ans = 'Yes'
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for word in magazine:        
        d[word]+=1
    for word in note:
        if d[word] == 0:

            ans = 'No'
            break
        else:
            d[word]-=1
    print(ans)
```

in most of codes i try to solve i face timeout errors on huge list. i try to keep coding and after so much failure i get demotivated and waste my time on online games. i really need to get a job soon, please someone guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `TLE` because looking up elements in `lists` take `O(n)` time. But the second solution is fast because it uses a `dictionary` and it takes constant time for looking up times i.e `O(1)`.